# How to solve docker getting error 0xffffffff?

Tags: linux, docker, installation, wsl-2, windows-11

I installed docker and wsl 2 according to the instructions, but an error occurred.

```
An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command. Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.

Please try shutting WSL down (wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting your computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be fully reinstalled. As a last resort, try to uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

Error details: 2 errors occurred:
* provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying "docker-desktop": importing WSL distro "Error: 0xffffffff\r\r\n" output="docker-desktop": running WSL command "wsl.exe --import docker-desktop C: \\Users\\Dark1\\AppData\\Local\\Docker\\wsl\\distro C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\wsl\\wsl-bootstrap.tar
--version 2 " failed with output "Error: 0xffffffff\r\r\n": exit status 0xffffffff
* checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be found.
```

I've tried all the methods on the internet and YouTube but the result is still the same

Answer (score 0):

if you are windows use just open cmd and follow the process

make sure the ubuntu running is not there you have to remove it using the following command wsl --unregister Ubuntu this will work for sure

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl -l -v
NAME                   STATE           VERSION

- Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --unregister Ubuntu
Unregistering.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl -l -v
NAME                   STATE           VERSION

- docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2